# SAS regresses missing values

Tags: sas, regression

For some reason when SAS does proportional hazards regression it is including those observations that are specified as . as a group in the results.  I suspect it has something to do with how I created my variable (and that SAS thinks my numeric variables are characters) but I can't figure out what I did wrong.  I am using SAS 9.4

```
data final; set final;
if edu_d = 'hs less' then edu_regress = 1;
else if edu_d = 'hs' then edu_regress = 1;
else if edu_d = 'some college' then edu_regress = 2;
else if edu_d = 'college plus' then edu_regress = 3;
else if edu_d = 'missing' then edu_regress=.;
run;
```

Then I run my regression:

```
proc phreg data=final;
class edu_regress;
model fuptime*dc(0)=edu_regress/rl;
run;
```

And the output is as follows:

```
edu_regress . 1 0.10963 0.12941 0.7177 0.3969 1.116 0.866 1.438  
edu_regress 1 1 0.22514 0.10949 4.2278 0.0398 1.252 1.011 1.552 
edu_regress 2 1 0.21706 0.11410 3.6190 0.0571 1.242 0.993 1.554
```

Where . is a category instead of treated as missing.

I'm sure I'm making a rookie mistake but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: I suggest you add the column headings to your output.  I assume Parameter, DF, Parameter_Estimate, etc?

Comment: Post the proc contents from the final dataset please.

Comment: I tested this with sample data and cannot replicate the problem on SAS 9.4 UNLESS it's a character variable. I think you're correct and your variable is actually character, which you can verify via PROC CONTENTS.

Comment: I agree with @Reeza. Also, check your log from the data step.  If EDU_REGRESS is a character variable, you will see a note about the numeric values you coded (1, 2, 3, .), being converted to character values. It's helpful to treat such a note as a warning or error message.

Comment: Thank you, yes I hadn't been paying attention to the error message.  Joe's fix worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I would clear your output, and re-run the code, and check the log and output.

As I read the docs, to get missing values treated as a category you would need to have `/missing` on your CLASS statement, which you do not have in the code shown.  Without that, I think missing values should be automatically excluded.

When I run PHREG with a CLASS variable that has missing values, I get a note in the log about observations being deleted due to missing values, and the output shows that the number of observations used is less than the number of observations read.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!  I did have that error message which I didn't know how to deal with, but now I've got it.

Answer (score 0):

If SAS thinks `edu_regress` is character, that's possible if it already was on the dataset as character.  This is one reason not to do `data x; set x;` and instead make a new dataset.  You should see notes in the datastep when you run it the way you have now regarding numeric to character conversion, if this is indeed the problem.

Anyway, one way to adjust this is to use CALL MISSING. It sets a variable to missing correctly regardless of the type.

```
data final; 
  set final;
  if edu_d = 'hs less' then edu_regress = 1;
  else if edu_d = 'hs' then edu_regress = 1;
  else if edu_d = 'some college' then edu_regress = 2;
  else if edu_d = 'college plus' then edu_regress = 3;
  else if edu_d = 'missing' then call missing(edu_Regress);
run;
```